# Making a new channel discord.js v11.3

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a ticket bot, but I'm not sure what is wrong with my `!new` command. Please help. I'm using what discord has in their [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Guild?scrollTo=createChannel) The code is below.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    message.react('✅');

    let modrole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Staff');

    if (!modrole) {
        console.log('Err: ModRole Not Found');
    }

    message.reply(`${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`);
    message.guild.createChannel(`${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`, {

        parent: '',
        topic: message.author.id,
        type: '',
        permissionOverwrites: [
            { id: message.guild.id, deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'] },
            { id: modrole.id, allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'] },
            { id: message.author.id, allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'] }

        ]
    }).then(c => {
        message.reply(`, <@Staff>`)
        const embed = new Discord.message.embed()
        .setTitle('**New Ticket**')
        .setDescription(`Thank you for opening a ticket *<@${message.author.id}>, a staff member will be with you shortly!`)
    })

}

//name this whatever the command name is.
module.exports.help = {
  name: "new"
}
```

These are the errors:

```
(node:1664) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.guild.createChannel is not a function
    at Object.module.exports.run (C:\Users\8fwbu\Desktop\CodeTProj\Molten Dev\commands\new.js:20:19)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\8fwbu\Desktop\CodeTProj\Molten Dev\main.js:42:31)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\8fwbu\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\8fwbu\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\8fwbu\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\8fwbu\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\8fwbu\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\8fwbu\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:1664) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)     
(node:1664) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: The Discord.JS maintainers are now urging v11 users to update to v12; As stage channels will now break v11

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you're not running Discord.js V11. If you installed Discord.js using the following command (Or updated it using the same command)

```
npm install discord.js
```

You're working on Discord.js V12. In Discord.js V12, `<Guild>.createChannel` is not a function. Instead, you'll use `<Guild>.channels.create()`. If you wish to return to Discord.js V11, you can use this command. This will overwrite the current Discord.js package with the most recent Discord.js V11 update.

```
npm install discord.js@11
```

The `@11` indicates that you want V11, not V12.

Additionally, I would like to point out that putting a hashtag (#) in the title is **not** recommended or allowed by Discord. The channel will be created, except the hashtag will be excluded from the channel name which will result in something like this: `User#0000 => #user0000`. Also keep in mind that certain unicode characters are prohibited from Discord and will not be accepted.

Comment: Appreciate the help. Ill try it and also ill remove the `#`